# How to formalize the fact that $f(i)=\lceil i/2\rceil$ is surjective but not one-to-one from $\Bbb N$ to itself?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> If the set $S$ is countably infinite, prove or disprove that if $f$ maps $S$ onto $S$ (i.e. $f\colon S\to S$ is a surjective function), then $f$ is one-to-one mapping.
>
> Please give a formal mathematical proof for this statement.

I have a counter-example: Suppose the mapping is from $\Bbb N$ (the natural numbers, a countably infinite set) to $\Bbb N$. And $f(i) = \lceil i/2\rceil$. It is onto function but not one-one.

But I am not getting that how this mapping is onto. Intuitively, since $1$ and $2$ will be mapped to $1$; $3$ and $4$ will be mapped to $2$; $5$ and $6$ will be mapped to $3$; similarly, $n-1$ and $n$ will be mapped to $n/2$. So in the codomain, there will be some elements that have no pre-image for this countably infinite set. So, please correct me where I am wrong.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: "So in the codomain, there will be some elements that have no pre-image for this countably infinite set." Why do you say that?  You just seemed to give an argument that it would.  Anyway for any $n$ then both $2n$ and $2n+1$ will map to $n$.  So $f$ is onto.

Comment: sir , since , cardinality of both sets are same and every 2 elements of domain are mapped to one element of codomain . so intuitively , it looks that some elements of codomain will not have any pre-image. please correct me

Comment: You just should that $1,2,3$ and $\frac n2$ (assuming $n$ is even) all have pre-images.  *What* elements don't have pre-images?  I honestly don't understand why you said that.

Comment: Are you thinking because you will run out of elements?  But the set is infinite.  You will never run out.  So it's perfectly fine to have 2, 3 or even an infinite number of elements all map to the same element and still be onto.  In fact that is *exactly* what you are proving.  It is possible to be surjective and not 1-1.

Comment: but |S| = n and I have shown that onle n/2 element have pre-images. so according to me,  n-(n/2)  elements will not have pre-image

Comment: But $|S|= \infty$.  Not a finite $n$.  So $n-\frac n2$ is not a valid number.

Comment: yes , that's why I said intuitively... it is infinite but cardinality is same from S-->S . if possible then please give any mathematical proof for this statement

Comment: If $|S| =n$ a finite number then every onto function is 1-1 (and vice versa).  But if $|S| = \infty$ that is not the case.

Comment: The cardinality is the same.  But it is not a finite number.  There is no such thing as $\infty - \frac {\infty}{2}$.  For any $k$ you can draw $2k$ and $2k-1$ and do that forever and never run out.

Comment: ok sir got it.. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

To prove that a function $f\colon A\to B$ is surjective, you need to be able to prove that given $b\in B$, there is some $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$.

In your case, $A=B=\Bbb N$, and $f(x)=\lceil \frac x2\rceil$.

So you need to prove that given any $m\in\Bbb N$, there is some $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $\lceil\frac n2\rceil=m$. Even though this $n$ is not unique, I am sure that you can come up with a way to find such $n$, from a given $m$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something. For every n in codomain, 2n and 2n-1 are in preimage, so the mapping is onto but not 1-1

Comment: sir , it may or may not be one-one